# Fazer comentário com ajuda em perguntas fora de escopo

Tags: suporte, comentários

Hoje me deparei com esta pergunta:

[Tela azul "ATTEMPTED WRITE TO READONLY MEMORY", como posso resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355982/tela-azul-attempted-write-to-readonly-memory-como-posso-resolver)

Obviamente foi justamente fechada por não pertencer ao escopo do site. Mas me surgiu uma dúvida:

Pensei em fazer um comentário na pergunta dando uma dica ao usuário sobre o problema de hardware enfrentado, MAS, por ser uma pergunta totalmente fora de escopo, fiquei com receio se eu podia fazer esse comentário.

Tive esse receio porque tenho notado que a área de comentários também é uma parte do site onde deve ser levada em consideração o seu conteúdo, ou seja, evitar criar conteúdo alheios ao propósito do site ou ao tópico, debates longos etc.

Para sanar essa dúvida, gostaria de saber da comunidade ou da moderação se eu poderia ter feito **apenas 1 comentário** de forma a ajudar no problema descrito, mesmo sendo ele fora do escopo. Como destaquei em negrito, seria apenas 1 comentário e caso o usuário que fez a pergunta quisesse alongar entrando em mais detalhes ou pedindo mais esclarecimentos, eu não iria responder mais.

Bom, isso é só um caso a mais dentre vários outros que já vi.

Qual a visão da comunidade em relação a isso? Eu poderia ter feito esse comentário (no singular) afim de fornecer alguma ajuda, mesmo sendo a pergunta fora de escopo?

Comment: Sim, pode fazer o comentário. Se a pergunta está fechada não tem respostas, acaba excluída pelo sistema depois de um tempo, e o comentário vai junto.

Comment: Ah tah rs.. Obg pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Eu não faria, se foge do escopo não faz muito sentido.

Comment: @Cadu Aí vai da vontade de cada um. Nada contra dar umas dicas por comentário se estiver disposto. Claro que dentro dos limites possíveis com comentários. E de preferência sem precisar usar um monte de comentários :)

Comment: Tb tenho visto isso, principalmente quando o usuário apenas pede alguma "dica" de Plugin, ou Link para Tutoriais ou Livros, etc.. O que que custa indicar um link pro cara... Quando a pergunta é baseada em opinião raramente eu comento, pq acredito que é  uma discussão que não vai levar a lugar nenhum, mesmo assim as vezes eu dou alguma dica pro sujeito... Meu único receio é estar alimentando um tipo de comportamento nas perguntas que possa comprometer o bom funcionamento e qualidade das novas perguntas no futuro.

Comment: Eu justamente opto por ajudar em comentário quando é fora, mesmo estando aberta (principalmente antes de ser mod, pq hoje se for evidente eu posso fechar), independente do assunto. Sou a favor de ajudar quem quer que seja no assunto que for, desde que na forma adequada. Se pesquisar meus comentários vai localizar muitos e muitos "fora de escopo".

Comment: Acho interessante prestar tal ajuda **via comentário**. Ainda que seja mais de um comentário. Haja vista que a pergunta será removida posteriormente pela moderação. Dentro desse intervalo, sua ajuda pode ser útil ao colega. A final, o objetivo da comunidade é compartilhar conhecimentos e ajudar o próximo. Lógico que junto do seu comentário, vai a sinalização, o votedown, etc e tal... Acho até que seria interessante criar um chat com o cara e, depois da conversa, fechar a sala... E claro, mencionar o escopo da comunidade pro colega não voltar a fazer tal tipo de pergunta...